# Why does my Lm722 Monitor only display the screen for a few seconds before turning black?

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors, windows-11, hdmi

I have been trying to connect my Acer laptop to my monitor, but whenever I plug in the HDMI cable, it will only display for a few seconds before turning black. I have tracked the native resolution from the monitor manual, and have also tried numerous other refresh rates and resolutions. Fairly sure that there are no broken pins in the VGA cable/adapter. This monitor has been able to connect to other laptops in the past. The buttons on the monitor do work, as I have seen them working in the small intervals where it actually displays something.

Comment: Are you able to try a different monitor? That will helpfully divide the problem in two.